# What is my webserver webapp directory?

Tags: maven, web-applications, webserver

I'm new at Maven and I'm following a tutorial where I learned how to create a Maven web app and now I want to run it from Eclipse IDE. In this tutorial the last step is this:

[image]

I don't understand how can I find my webserver web app directory and how can I restart my webserver. Someone explaining me this? 
Regards,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to deploy your java webapplication to tomcat semi-automatically I suggest you to use the tomcat-maven plugin (section 3):

[Tutorial on tomcat-maven plugin](http://o7planning.org/en/10133/run-maven-java-web-application-in-tomcat-maven-plugin)

Comment: Thanks! Im gonna try it! Does it work with Eclipse Mars?

Comment: Yes. The only negative thing: you have to stop your application before redeployment (mentioned in the tutorial) Otherwise you get an error  (port already in use). If that happen restart eclipse.

Comment: Ok.It says to insert apache.org dependencies into pom.xml but I have to insert some other dependencies. Can I add as mush dependencies as I want? And can I install tomcat apache from eclipse?

Comment: You only have to copy the <plugins></plugins> section into your pom.xml file and configure the run configuration as described

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped.